# On RDS, an application is asking for admin rights everytime

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2012, remote-desktop, rds, uac

I have a 2012 R2 server with some RDS users. One of the applications, that is locally installed, is asking them for administrative permissions everythime it runs. This annoys my users and the only workaround I have found is to add them to the Administrators group which is a wrong solution.

Users and server belong to a domain. I have tried adding read/execute permissions for "Users", "Domain users" and nothing works. Also tried on the "compatibility tab" to set "Run as administrator for all users" with no luck.

It seems UAC us working here, but I need to solve this as no user wants to enter credentials each and everythime they run the application.

This is a trusted application but unsigned... what ca we do?.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

Came across same issue.  We have published an application as RemoteApp collection. The solution which worked for us is by removing (uncheck the checkbox) "Run as Administrator" from the application short cut.